# Having trouble uploading image to firebase using expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, expo, firebase-storage

I am trying to just add a feature of uploading system files on firestore using expo image picker,the image picker function is working but im having trouble uploading the file
Following is my Firebase.js configuration

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";



const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCyRySTTsdv1sTyoe5195a2u5zS65K17wg",
  authDomain: "uber-eats-clone-373817.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "uber-eats-clone-373817",
  storageBucket: "uber-eats-clone-373817.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "481043880464",
  appId: "1:481043880464:web:e35e3c92bb7c9860878895"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app =initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// const storage = firebase.storage().ref('gs://uber-eats-clone-373817.appspot.com');
const auth = getAuth(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);
export {auth,app,firebase,storage}
```

ImageUpload.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import {app,storage} from '../Firebase'
import { View ,StyleSheet,Button,Image} from 'react-native'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'





function ImageUpload() {
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null)
const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false)
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,   
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };
  const uploadImage = async () => {
    console.log(app.name);
    const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function() {
        resolve(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.onerror = function() {
        reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
      };
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.open('GET', image, true);
      xhr.send(null);
    })
   
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    const fileName = `Image_${randomNum}_${'image'}`;
    const ref = storage.ref().child(`Pictures/${fileName}`)
    const snapshot = ref.put(blob)
    snapshot.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      ()=>{
        setUploading(true)
      },
      (error) => {
        setUploading(false)
        console.log(error)
        blob.close()
        return 
      },
      () => {
        snapshot.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
          setUploading(false)
          console.log("Download URL: ", url)
          setImage(url)
          blob.close()
          return url
        })
      }
      )
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {image && <Image source={{uri: image}} style={{width: 170 , height: 200}}/>}
      <Button title='Select Image' onPress={pickImage} />
      {!uploading ? <Button title='Upload Image' onPress={uploadImage} />: <ActivityIndicator size={'small'} color='black' />}
    </View>
  )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 15,
    backgroundColor:'none',
    border:'none'
  },
  
});

export default ImageUpload
```

I get the following error when i try to upload the image

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: *Firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3*_.storage.ref is not a function
> at uploadImage$ (ImageUpload.js:45:1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing the new modular syntax of the v9 and later SDKs with the namespaced syntax of the older SDKs. You should use one or the other, not both.

To [create a reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/create-reference#create_a_reference) to a file in the modular syntax, you should import and call the top-level `ref` function. From the link:

```
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

// Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
const storage = getStorage();

// Create a storage reference from our storage service
const storageRef = ref(storage);
```

To subsequently [upload a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file) to that reference, call the top-level `uploadBytes` as shown in the documentation link. And similarly follow the example in the documentation to [get a download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) for the file once you've uploaded it.

Comment: yes thanks i checked the documentation and changed accordingly.